# Eventhandlers between different forms (parent/child)

Tags: forms, c++-cli, parent-child, eventhandler

Im quite new with c++ and so far im having a little trouble understanding the basics. i got 2 forms right now.

parent.h

```
#include "child.h"
public ref class parent : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
  child^ v_child = gcnew child;
  void InitializeComponent(void){ 
    v_child->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(v_child, &child::child_Load);
  }
  private: System::Void child_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    MessageBox::Show("Howdy");
  }
}
```

i basically want the parent to do something when the child has an event, in this case, just a Load. it compiles and gives no warning/error, child execute the event, but it never triggers on the parent.
wanted to do this to be able to interact between parent and child, which so far, im having so much trouble doing so.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, do you want `parent` to react to a "Load" event on the child?

If so, then you're linking the event incorrectly.  Your code:

```
v_child->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(v_child, &child::child_Load);
```

Links the Load event handler to the `v_child` not to `parent`.  Try this instead:

```
    v_child->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &parent::child_Load);
```